# How to check exit code in bash in one line/statement?

Tags: bash

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e # I can't remove this line!

if [ docker inspect foo ]; then
  echo container is present
else
  echo container is absent
fi
```

Is it possible? `docker inspect foo` returns exit code `1` when container is absent and `0` when it's present.

Now I'm getting this:

```
-bash: [: too many arguments
```

Comment: The question isn't clear to me.  Since your code is not a one-liner are you asking how to write it as a one-liner?

Comment: I'm going to retract my answer.  I don't think you can do it at all since "-e" causes the entire script to exit whenever it runs a command that returns a non-zero status.

Comment: You say you can't remove the `set -e` line. Are you allowed to put `set +e` on the next line to turn off the -e flag?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to run the command within the "if" statement, you'd do it like this:

```
if docker inspect foo
then
  echo container is present
else
  echo container is absent
fi
```

All of the line breaks can be omitted or replaced by semicolons if you want. This would also work:

```
if docker inspect foo; then echo container is present; else echo container is absent; fi
```

If you want something more compact, you could use this kind of syntax:

```
docker inspect foo && echo container is present
docker inspect foo || echo container is absent
docker inspect foo && echo container is present || echo container is absent
```

`&&` runs the second command if the first succeeded. `||` runs the second command if the first one *failed*. The last line uses both forms.

Comment: Warning: the `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3` idiom is not the same as `if cmd1; then cmd2; else cmd3; fi`, because it will execute `cmd3` if *either* `cmd1` or `cmd2` fails. If the second command is an `echo` this is unlikely (but possible); in other cases it might be an issue.

Comment: what if I want to `echo container` only on specific exit code (e.g `1` or `2`)?

Comment: @DrSensor pls refer to this bash cheat sheet (or maybe start a new question if you need more direction).  https://devhints.io/bash#conditionals

Comment: I'd add to the answer that you can use `if docker inspect foo > /dev/null 2>&1` if you don't care about the docker output.

Answer (score -1):

A different approach will be something like:

```
$ test $(podman inspect foo &> /dev/null) && echo container is present ||  echo container is absent

container is absent
```